# What happened to rhetoric as a branch of philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, rhetoric

Long long ago, rhetoric was a branch of philosophy. As far as I can tell, nowadays there is no philosophical work in the domain of persuasion and argumentation; this is now done in the public-relations and communications, fields that (again as far as I can tell) have very weak philosophical underpinnings.

Assuming rhetoric has died as a philosophical topic, when and how did that occur?

Comment: It has disappeared after the Renaissance, following the rejection of rethoric as a tool for improving knowledge by the founding fathers of Early Modern Science, like Descartes. For a recent proposed "revival", see [Chaïm Perelman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha%C3%AFm_Perelman)'s works, e.g. [The New Rhetoric : A Treatise on Argumentation](https://books.google.it/books?id=aPTWAAAAMAAJ) (original ed.,1958).

Comment: Informal logic focuses on persuasion and argumentation.  It's a relatively niche topic in contemporary academic philosophy, where "logic" usually means formal logic.  Stanford Encyclopedia article:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-informal/

Comment: see also: [trivium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium) and [rhetoric history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric#History), http://ashr.org/ and http://www.artofmanliness.com/2010/11/30/history-of-rhetoric/

Comment: Wikipedia's rhetoric entry has a [Modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric#Modern) section, currently the more commonly used term is [argumentation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentation_theory).

Comment: You might also want to investigate [parrhesia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrhesia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The historical events are complex...

In a nutshell, during Renaissance there were a "revival" of Rhetoric (as part of [Dialectic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#DiaArgArtDia), and thus [linked to logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#DiaRhe)) as a "tool" for discovering new knowledge (a "method") as opposed to traditional Aristotelian logic (syllogism) as the fundamental tool for science.

See e.g. [Pierre de La Ramée](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ramus/#LogiMeth) and his concern with *Inventio*.

The debate "raged" for more than a century; we can see also [Jacopo Zabarella](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zabarella/#4) and the debate on *methodus* and *regressus*. We can still found it into [Francis Bacon](https://books.google.it/books?id=RHkOSmSc530C&pg=PA37)'s works.

But the "methodological" debate had no "effective" impact : **no** new scientific discoveries were made possible either by traditional logic or by Rhetoric-based "methods"

Early modern science was made possible by a unique mixture of new ideas, experiences (and experiments) and mathematical (analytical) tools : from Tycho and Kepler, through William Gilbert and William Harvey to the "founding fathers" of new science : Galileo, Descartes and Newton.

With them the "methodus" become mathematics : neither syllogism nor *inventio*. See e.g. [Descartes' search for method](https://books.google.it/books?id=QVwDs_Ikad0C&pg=PA104).

Some secondary sources :

- Charles Schmitt & Quentin Skinner (editors), [The Cambridge History of Renaissance Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=jJnyxg3xxTEC&pg=PR3) (1988) : **Part 2.V Logic and language**;
- Daniel Garber & Michael Ayers (editors), [The Cambridge History of Seventeenth-century Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=5l2dDAEACAAJ) (1998) : **Part II Logic, language, and abstract objects**;
- Neal Gilbert, [Renaissance Concepts of Method](https://books.google.it/books?id=tXQ6vgAACAAJ) (1960);
- Walter Ong, [Ramus, Method, and the Decay of Dialogue: From the Art of Discourse to the Art of Reason](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZSeEzVKMghoC) (1958);
- Paolo Rossi, [Francis Bacon: From Magic to Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=NkI_wVrVzXMC&printsec=frontcover) (original ed,. 1968);
- Stephen Gaukroger, [Francis Bacon and the Transformation of Early-Modern Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=RHkOSmSc530C&printsec=frontcover) (2001);
- Marco Sgarbi, [The Aristotelian Tradition and the Rise of British Empiricism : Logic and Epistemology in the British Isles (1570-1689)](https://books.google.it/books?id=rrDoNX12yZEC&pg=PA1) (2013);
- Stephen Gaukroger, [Cartesian Logic: An Essay on Descartes's Conception of Inference](https://books.google.it/books?id=VZ_vF2dNTAEC) (1989);
- W.A. Wallace, [Galileo’s Logic of Discovery and Proof: The Background, Content, and Use of His Appropriated Treatises on Aristotle’s Posterior Analytics](https://books.google.it/books?id=qWoyBwAAQBAJ) (1992).

Comment: Could you add what (some of) these sources say about the relationship between rhetoric and philosophy?